# Wordpress: update and preview buttons redirect to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange problem with wordpress: every time I try to write / update / preview a post with the code below, it redirects me to the home page.

Here is the code:

```
$segments = \Uri::segments();
if (empty($segments))
    $segments[0] = 'homepage';
```

Other useful information:

- I have last Wordpress version
- I've tried cleaning the cache
- I've tried with a fresh install
- I've tried without any plugin nor any custom theme
- All other post works well, even the one with other source code
- The error log is empty

Hope you can help because I don't know what else to do.

**UPDATE 1**

This is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**UPDATE 2**

As I said before, I'm redirected to the home page if I insert that 3 line in the post and then if I try to insert / update / preview a post. BUT, if I copy past on the toolbar the preview link, it works (don't know if it can help)...

**UPDATE 3: RESOLVED**

Finally found the problem: it was a Mod_Security rule in the server that redirects to the home page in case it happens. Finally it works again :).
Thank again for helping

Comment: That code is seriously not an valid code , read first about how `OOP` works. check this link out and read about oop : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

Comment: Thansk for the answe but please read the question: the code is not used to add / change functionality to wordpress, it is used inside a post as a tutorial. Even if not related to the question, the code worked when the article was written and it was related to a PHP framework. EDIT: I deleted class declaration since the problem is caused only by these 3 lines, without them everything works fine.

Comment: This can have multiple reasons.. how does your .htaccess look like?

Comment: "used inside the post as a tutorial" ...this php code is located where? in the content?

Comment: @caramba: I've editet the code and added the .htaccess content in the post.

Comment: @David: that's the only content: in order to understand the problem I've tried to delete everything from the post. If I create a new post / update an old one / preview a post with that 3 lines, I'm redirected to the home page.

Comment: your .htaccess looks fine. can you change the template while editing your post? what is the reason for redirect? did you check if you get a 404 at first place?

Comment: @caramba: I've removed every template and plugin (deactivating them and deleting the folders) to be sure was not relate to one of them, but the problem was still there. I think it is related to the configuration of the server.

Comment: odd its not even a redirect, php wont run in the content, its saved in the db as a string. There are plugins to do this but they rely on php tags. I'd actually post this on the WP forum, maybe its validation on post content but i'm not on the latest version so it didn't happen to me. I don't think there is any apache setting but maybe a script to detect script on page so that would be the 2nd call.

Comment: @David: thank you very much, I'll try to ask in the Wordpress support forum :-).

Comment: Found the problem: it was a Mod_Security rule in the server used for it. Finally it works again :).
Thank again for helping

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you expected, but your code and you `.htaccess` file look fine and I don't think that this is a *"redirect problem"*.

When you said:

> I've removed every template and plugin (deactivating them and deleting the folders) to be sure was not relate to one of them, but the problem was still there.

It sounds like there *might* be a problem with your server (possibly even wordpress itself).
I think you should report this problem to wordpress, maybe even file it as *possible* bug.

Good luck and all the best.

Comment: Marco, have you solved this problem or found out what it was?

Comment: Not yet, I've opened a bug on wordpress asking in the support forum, but no answer received so far... I'm thinking about moving to Ghost since I'm really frustrated.

Comment: @MarcoPace OK then, good to know. Good luck to you & all the best :)

Comment: Found the problem: it was a Mod_Security rule in the server used for it. Finally it works again :).
Thank again for helping

Comment: @MarcoPace Any time, I'm happy that it's worked for you. Also if my post has helped you feel free to up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access to your virtual host file? Maybe a rule on the configuration file is doing the redirect. Also, check your permalink settings, try changing the permalink structure and then see if the preview works.

Additionally, could you add your functions.php theme file so we can take a look at it? Perhaps a custom function is causing this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I've changed the permalink to use the default one without success. Regarding the function.php, I had the same problem even changing theme, so I don't think is theme-related.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously had a non updated plugin such as rev-slider you may find that your security has been breached and something was modified to prevent you from doing an update. If this is the case there are some things you can do but look at the .htaccess for redirects and also if necessary compare the main files against the release version you have running for little differences. Assume you have tried disabling all plugins and switching back to default theme etc?
You say that you have explored all of these .. I would then be looking to do command line tests using curl or similar to view the headers to see what is going on.
In the options you could try changing to url formatting options (permalink) for posts and pages through WP console - this can help flush through changes caused by templates etc. You can change them back .. there are a couple of places by memory that you can do this but it's been a while so can't give more explicit links.
Your symptoms at a quick glance smell like a permalink setting that has hung around and needs updating.

Comment: Thansk Peter for the response, I've tried to see headers and I've 2 different header response based on the result: when it works well I receive a "302 Moved Temporarily" status; when it doesn't work I receive a "302 Found" status. So something is different, but I can-t figure out what exactly.